# C# IsMDIParent Container LabVIEW

Tags: c#, dll, labview, mdi

I have some C# code that allows the user to control a LabVIEW VI from a C# Windows Forms application.

As of right now, when the user clicks on the "open dialog" button, it opens the VI in another separate, LabVIEW-styled window. What I would like, if possible, is to have that window open as a child form inside the parent.

Everything else works as far as the LabVIEW/C# interface. I just would like to have everything self-contained in one aesthetically pleasing window.

Here's Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LabVIEW_DLL_Call
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("SharedLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern long Launch();

        [DllImport("SharedLib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern long SetParams(ushort signalType, double frequency, double amplitude);

        [DllImport("SharedLib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern long GetData(double[] Array, long len);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Launch();
            var hWnd = FindWindow("dialog.vi", null);
            SetParent(hWnd, panel1.Handle);
        }

        private void btnSetParams_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetParams((ushort)this.dropSignalType.SelectedIndex, (double)this.numFreq.Value, (double)this.numAmplitude.Value);
        }

        private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dataCount = 1000;
            double[] results = new double[dataCount];
            GetData(results, dataCount);
            string txt = String.Join("\r\n", results);
            this.textBox1.Text = txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what happens is that Form2 loads up within Form1, but it also generates the LabVIEW window. (And the second photo is one of the launch.vi)

[image: c# program screenshot]

[image: launch.vi]

Comment: `long code = Launch();`  May we see `Launch()`?  Looks like a different process.  Use [Process.WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=netframework-4.7.2), then pass [Process.MainWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) API.

Comment: Search for how to find the [MdiClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mdiclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)  of your main MDI form to use as the "parent" in the SetParent() call.

Comment: @Idle_Mind This is where it gets I think a little tricky, because Launch() isn't contained in any of the C# code. It is build-in to the LabVIEW project. When I compile the DLL in LabVIEW the header file generates: `int32_t __cdecl Launch(void);` (Also, I've updated my original post to include a screenshot of the launch.vi.

Comment: Hmm...another approach would be to `Launch()`, then start polling with a timer looking for a top level window that starts with "dialog.vi".  Use the [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) API, which returns a handle to the window.  Then you can pass that handle to SetParent() as outlined before.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks for the help. I ditched the double-form method for the "FindWindow/SetParent" method. I created a panel in Form1, and changed the btnLaunch_Click. (see above edit). Still isn't working. I'm a little new to this procedure, so a little more guidance would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a great start!

It could look something like this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;

    private async void btnLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool foundIt = false;
        DateTime timeOut = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        Launch();
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(250);
            var hWnd = FindWindow(null, "dialog.vi");
            if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                SetParent(hWnd, panel1.Handle);
                SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
                foundIt = true;
            }
        }
        while (!foundIt && (DateTime.Now <= timeOut));
        if (!foundIt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to find the LabView window.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just had to mess around with the SetWindowPos a little to get the position/sizing correct.

Comment: Be aware the the user can still grab that window and move it around inside your "container".  You can add a "Redock" button to find it again and reposition it.